# Error: null character for <input concatenated stream>

Tags: lisp

Edit: Figured out the initial problem. Now it says that there is no function sel2, and I'm not sure why it thinks I'm calling a function when sel2 is a list. It looks like it's being referred to as a list to me.

I feel like I'm doing something stupid, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I'm supposed to make a function that reverses a list (can use the reverse function) and a function that detects if a list contains a palindrome. So far, I have:

```
 (defun Myreverse (sel)

    (return-from Myreverse (reverse sel))
)

(defun Palindrome (sel2)
    (if (= sel2 (reverse (sel2)))
        (return-from Palindrome (write "Yes"))
    )
    (write "No")
)

(Myreverse '(1 2 3 4))
```

Does anyone know what I"m doing wrong? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

```
READ from #<INPUT CONCATENATED-STREAM #<INPUT UNBUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER @7>>: illegal character #\Null
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's difficult to say what you are doing wrong, since you didn't tell us what you are doing. There is some code and a message. But what did you do? Who was printing that message?

Comment: I copy and pasted the code into the lisp console

Comment: And I did say what I am doing... I'm making two functions and calling one of them (myreverse).

Comment: what 'Lisp console'? Best also to show us input and output. We can not always guess what you use and how you use it...

Comment: you might also want to check the use of SEL2 in the function Palindrome. You call it as a function SEL2 - why?

Comment: I'm using GNU CLISP. When I load it, a console window pops up. I copy and paste the code directly into the console and press enter. The error message pops up. Anyway, I figured out the problem. Apparently I'm supposed to save the code in a standalone file and then load it using the load command: (load "C:\\Users\\...."). I will look into your comment about sel2. thanks!

Comment: Now I get the error message that there is no function sel2, as you predicted. I'm not sure how it's being called as a function though... I'm trying to set it so that if the reverse of a list equals the original, then it is a palindrome. It looks like it's being referred to as a variable to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question, per comments above. Also solved the function call problem.

New code:

```
(defun Myreverse (sel)

    (reverse sel)
)

(defun Palindrome (pal)
    (equal pal (reverse pal))
)
```

Comment: The variable REV is not declared anywhere. It is undefined. It's also not needed.